# Convert Oracle rolling 4 weeks statement to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Could someone assist me with converting the Oracle statement below to SQL Server? The objective is to look at the date column and determine if it is within the rolling 4 weeks.

```
CASE
WHEN CC.CLIENT_ORDER_RECEIVED_DATE BETWEEN (next_day (trunc(sysdate,'DD'),'FRIDAY'))-13 AND next_day (trunc(sysdate,'DD'),'FRIDAY')-6 THEN (next_day (trunc(sysdate,'DD'),'FRIDAY')-7)
WHEN CC.CLIENT_ORDER_RECEIVED_DATE BETWEEN (next_day (trunc(sysdate,'DD'),'FRIDAY'))-20 AND next_day (trunc(sysdate,'DD'),'FRIDAY')-13 THEN (next_day (trunc(sysdate,'DD'),'FRIDAY')-14)
WHEN CC.CLIENT_ORDER_RECEIVED_DATE BETWEEN (next_day (trunc(sysdate,'DD'),'FRIDAY'))-27 AND next_day (trunc(sysdate,'DD'),'FRIDAY')-20 THEN (next_day (trunc(sysdate,'DD'),'FRIDAY')-21)
WHEN CC.CLIENT_ORDER_RECEIVED_DATE BETWEEN (next_day (trunc(sysdate,'DD'),'FRIDAY'))-34 AND next_day (trunc(sysdate,'DD'),'FRIDAY')-27 THEN (next_day (trunc(sysdate,'DD'),'FRIDAY')-28)
END AS ROLLING_4_WEEK_FLAG,
```

Answer (score 1):

Your oracle code seems to calculate the previous Fridays / Saturdays, so you can do similar thing in SQL Server with this:

```
dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

Since this works based on day 'zero' (=1.1.1900), which was Monday, so this will return always Monday of current week. So to get Saturday, you just have to add -2 days, and for Friday of course -3.

Comment: And of course if you use this on the weekend, you'll have to check that a little bit differently

Comment: Thanks James!  In order to repeat this to go back historically for the last 4 weeks how would I go about this?

Comment: For example `dateadd(day, -9, dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, dateadd(day, 2, getdate())), 0))` should be the same as `(next_day (trunc(sysdate,'DD'),'FRIDAY'))-13`. Not 100% sure since I can't test this, but the +2 days is to make sure if you run it on saturday or sunday you should get the same result.